# Add new values to PyQt chart to update the chart on demand

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to make a candlestick chart with pyqtgraph in PyQt5 that updates the graph with new data every time a method is called.
I have named this method dpoint.new_dpoint in the dpoint_var class which adds another row of randomized data to an array every time it is activated, to be read by the candlestick class.

I'm brushing up on my python after a long absence from it and I am just beginning to learn the PyQt library and trying to make sense of it.

As of right now I am having an issue with the result of this script.
For some reason when I run the script I get this error

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

---
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 99>()
     96 dpoint = dpoint_var()
     97 dpoint.new_dpoint()
---> 99 item = CandlestickItem(dpoint_var.data2)
    100 plt = pg.plot()
    101 plt.addItem(item)

Input In [5], in CandlestickItem.__init__(self, data)
     64 pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
     65 self.data = data  ## data must have fields: time, open, close, min, max
---> 66 self.generatePicture()

Input In [5], in CandlestickItem.generatePicture(self)
     72 p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
     73 p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
---> 74 width = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
     75 for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
     76     p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

which seems to indicate that the dpoint.new_dpoint method was not activated but I don't see why not.

Also I am trying to find a way to update the pyqtgraph from an external function rather than from inside the Qtimer function as I only want the data to refresh when new data is available from an external source, not at a regular interval.
What is the correct way to do this without redrawing the entire chart?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot, QtCore, QtGui
import sys 
import os
from random import randint

class dpoint_var:
    dpoint = 20
    data = np.empty((0,5), dtype = float)
    data2 = np.empty((0,5), dtype = float)
    def __init__(self):
        def return_dpoint():
            return self.dpoint
        

    def new_dpoint(self):
        self.data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0005, high=0.01, size=(self.dpoint,5))
        self.data2 = np.empty((self.dpoint,5), dtype = float)
        #set the first column to an ordered number line
        x = 0
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,0])):
            self.data2[i][0] = x
            x += 1

        #set the second column to the opening data
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,1])):
            if i > 10:        
                self.data2[i][1] = self.data[i-10][1]
            else:
                self.data2[i][1] = self.data[i][1] 


        #set the third column to the closing data
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,2])):
            self.data2[i][2] = self.data[i][1]


        #set the fourth column to the minimum bat value for the time period
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,3])):
            if i > 10:
                self.data2[i][3] = self.data[i-10:i, 1].min()

            else:
                for i in range(len(self.data[:,3])):
                    self.data2[i][3] = self.data[i][3]

        #set the fourth column to the minimum bat value for the time period
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,4])):
            if i > 10:
                self.data2[i][4] = self.data[i-1:i, 1].max()

            else:
                for i in range(len(self.data[:,4])):
                    self.data2[i][4] = self.data[i][4]
        dpoint.dpoint +=1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

## Create a subclass of GraphicsObject.
## The only required methods are paint() and boundingRect() 
## (see QGraphicsItem documentation)
class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data  ## data must have fields: time, open, close, min, max
        self.generatePicture()
    
    def generatePicture(self):
        ## pre-computing a QPicture object allows paint() to run much more quickly, 
        ## rather than re-drawing the shapes every time.
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        width = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(t-width, open, width*2, close-open))
        p.end()
    
    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)
    
    def boundingRect(self):
        ## boundingRect _must_ indicate the entire area that will be drawn on
        ## or else we will get artifacts and possibly crashing.
        ## (in this case, QPicture does all the work of computing the bouning rect for us)
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    


dpoint = dpoint_var()
dpoint.new_dpoint()

item = CandlestickItem(dpoint_var.data2)
plt = pg.plot()
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(dpoint.new_dpoint)
timer.start(1000)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT:

Thanks to suggestions from musicamante I managed to resolve the error. Thank you sir for your valuable advice :)

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot, QtCore, QtGui
import sys 
import os
from random import randint

class Dpoint_var:
    dpoint = 20

    def __init__(self):
        def return_dpoint():
            data = np.empty((0,5), dtype = float)
            data2 = np.empty((0,5), dtype = float)
            return self.dpoint


    def new_dpoint(self):
        self.data = np.random.uniform(low=0.0005, high=0.01, size=(self.dpoint,5))
        self.data2 = np.empty((self.dpoint,5), dtype = float)
        #set the first column to an ordered number line
        x = 0
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,0])):
            self.data2[i][0] = x
            x += 1

        #set the second column to the opening data
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,1])):
            if i > 10:        
                self.data2[i][1] = self.data[i-10][1]
            else:
                self.data2[i][1] = self.data[i][1] 


        #set the third column to the closing data
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,2])):
            self.data2[i][2] = self.data[i][1]


        #set the fourth column to the minimum bat value for the time period
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,3])):
            if i > 10:
                self.data2[i][3] = self.data[i-10:i, 1].min()

            else:
                for i in range(len(self.data[:,3])):
                    self.data2[i][3] = self.data[i][3]

        #set the fourth column to the minimum bat value for the time period
        for i in range(len(self.data[:,4])):
            if i > 10:
                self.data2[i][4] = self.data[i-1:i, 1].max()

            else:
                for i in range(len(self.data[:,4])):
                    self.data2[i][4] = self.data[i][4]
        dpoint.dpoint +=1

## Create a subclass of GraphicsObject.
## The only required methods are paint() and boundingRect() 
## (see QGraphicsItem documentation)
class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data  ## data must have fields: time, open, close, min, max
        self.generatePicture()

    def generatePicture(self):
        ## pre-computing a QPicture object allows paint() to run much more quickly, 
        ## rather than re-drawing the shapes every time.
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        width = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(t-width, open, width*2, close-open))
        p.end()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        ## boundingRect _must_ indicate the entire area that will be drawn on
        ## or else we will get artifacts and possibly crashing.
        ## (in this case, QPicture does all the work of computing the bouning rect for us)
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())



dpoint = Dpoint_var()
dpoint.new_dpoint()

item = CandlestickItem(dpoint.data2)
plt = pg.plot()
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(dpoint.new_dpoint)
timer.start(10)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However I am still having trouble finding the correct method to update the chart.
I want to be able tp update the chart from an external signal rather than from the Qtimer, however even in Qtimer I can't find the proper syntax to reload the chart.
The timer is supposedly adding new data to the array but it is not loading the chart.
However I can't figure out the syntax to do so. Qt library is so large, unstructured, and esoteric.

Any advice?

Comment: Some important suggestions: 1. a signal connection must use a *reference* to a callable, so the `timeout.connect` is wrong, as it should be `timer.timeout.connect(dpoint.new_dpoint)`, without parentheses; 2. creating and starting a timer *after* `app.exec()` is pointless: the timer must be created *before* that (or while the loop is running); 3. the error alone is not enough without context, please provide the full traceback of the error (run the program from a terminal or prompt if the IDE doesn't display the full debug message); 4. improve your imports, as they are quite a mess;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have edited the main post with the corrections.

Comment: Possible TYPO (unverifiable, since the code is not a [mre]): it should probably be `item = CandlestickItem(dpoint.data2)`. That's another *extremely important* reason for which classes should have capitalized names. Besides, unless you *really* know what you're doing, you should not use mutable types as class attributes, but as *instance* attributes (i.e. create them in the `__init__`).

Comment: Note: if that was the real reason of the problem, then carefully consider what written above: 1. if you had set `data2` as instance attribute, you'd probably found out more easily that you were referencing the class instead of the instance (because it would have raised an `AttributeError`); 2. if you had used a capitalized name for the class, you'd have spotted the issue even more easily, as you would have probably not mistaken `Dpoint_var` with `dpoint`: the first is a clearly a class (or, maybe, a constant), the second is probably a local *variable* (maybe an instance or a function).